# Recursive Makefile always remakes targets

Tags: makefile

I am trying to create a Makefile target which will call itself with different options.

```
# Include config.mk which sets design-specific variables
`include $(CONFIG)

# This command runs the script once with current options
$(LOG_DIR)/compare.log: $(RESULTS_DIR)/final.bin
  tclsh $(UTILS_DIR)/script.tcl | tee $@

# Alias for above command
compare: $(LOG_DIR)/compare.log

# This command runs make once for each config file
.PHONY: compare_all
compare_all:
  for config in designs/*/config.mk; do \
    $(MAKE) CONFIG=$$config compare; \
  done
  $(UTILS_DIR)/compare_all.py
```

The problem is that the `compare_all` target works as expected, but it *always* thinks that the sub-make targets are out-of-date.

When I run, for example

```
make CONFIG=designs/a/config.mk compare
make CONFIG=designs/b/config.mk compare
make CONFIG=designs/c/config.mk compare
```

I get:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'compare'.
make: Nothing to be done for 'compare'.
make: Nothing to be done for 'compare'.
```

But when I run `make compare_all -n`, I get

```
tclsh utils/script.tcl | tee logs/a/compare.log
tclsh utils/script.tcl | tee logs/b/compare.log
tclsh utils/script.tcl | tee logs/c/compare.log
```

showing that it's going to rebuild all designs even though they're already up-to-date.

Comment: You could make this problem much easier by preparing and posting a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There must be something different about your real environment than what you show here.  The `compare` target depends on `$(LOG_DIR)/6_compare_rc.log` but you have no recipe to build that target.  This makefile as-is would give an error saying something like "no rule to build" that file, unless it already exists (in which case, you would not see the `tclsh` command run) or else there's some other rule in the makefile you don't show.

Comment: Typo when copying - fixed now. It's just an alias for the above target.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your issue with a local example that mimicked what your makefile does (since it's not a complete example I had to fudge it).  I don't see anything in the makefile (I assume the backquote before the `include` is a typo in your question and not in your real makefile) that would cause this behavior so it must be something you haven't shown us.  All I can suggest is either (a) create a completely self-contained example for us to try, or (b) add the `-d` option to your make invocation and go through the debug output to see why make rebuilds.